# How can I add/replace language in the URL (string)?

Tags: php, regex

[Here is what I've tried so far](https://regex101.com/r/lMSpe7/8):

```
/(?:\/(en(\?|$)|fa(\?|$)))|\?/
```

---

**Inputs:**

```
http://localhost:8000/search/fa?q=sth
http://localhost:8000/search?q=sth
http://localhost:8000/search
http://localhost:8000/search/fa
```

**Expected Output:**

```
http://localhost:8000/search/en?q=sth
http://localhost:8000/search/en?q=sth
http://localhost:8000/search/en
http://localhost:8000/search/en
```

---

As you see, I need to match `?`, but not select it. Also I need to add `/en` in the end of third URL.

How can I fix my pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?\/(\w{2,})(?:\?(.*?)|)$
```

This may work

Here is a simple implementation with this regex.

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/NAqMt)

Comment: It would be much better if you add some explanations to your answer and make it more understandable for newbies like me .